# Programmatically add a shared calendar ical link to iOS and/or Android Devices

Tags: android, ios, calendar, icalendar

I'm trying to create a link that lets you select your operating system and then adds a shared calendar to the device using a long link provided.

It's for a site that requires the user to be logged in and then they can view their unique ical link to add as a shared calendar that displays their scheduled events.  However, the link is very long and I would like to programmatically add it to their device if possible as a new shared calendar.

Is this possible?  Thanks so much.